# Sea Glass L&F - Swing Components Class Casting Exception

Tags: java, swing, classcastexception, look-and-feel, seaglass

I developed my Java application in Swing. The application has been running fine until the time I added Sea Glass Look and Feel. When I disable Sea Glass L&F may the application will run fine. Sometimes it runs fine with Sea Glass L&F and sometimes it throws an exception. I understand that the Sea Glass L&F is causing this exception. I could post the **SSCCE/MCVE** but the application has many classes; However, the exception below shows what went wrong with  the application. The situation is similar to [this one here](https://code.google.com/p/seaglass/issues/detail?id=110).

**Qns** How do we solve this Class cast exception?

Below is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.seaglasslookandfeel.component.SeaGlassTitlePane cannot be cast to javax.swing.JScrollBar
at com.seaglasslookandfeel.state.ScrollBarButtonIsIncreaseButtonState.isInState(ScrollBarButtonIsIncreaseButtonState.java:44)
at com.seaglasslookandfeel.state.State.isInState(State.java:160)
at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyle.getExtendedState(SeaGlassStyle.java:1288)
at com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassStyle.get(SeaGlassStyle.java:997)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.getIcon(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"I could post the SSCCE/MCVE but the application has many classes;"*  So prepare an MCVE that does ***not*** have 'many classes', but just the necessary code to produce the error.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay let me do that.

Comment: talking about I can't run correctly on todays Java versions

Comment: there must be the same solution as for TItileBorders

Comment: @AndrewThompson I prepared the MCVE but this one is not throwing any exceptions! I think the problem is related to the "third part package" -Sea Glass -because sometimes the error is shown and sometimes not.

Comment: Well, looks like you're better off a) using a different PLAF or b) taking it back to the makers of the sea glass PLAF or c) both.  Really nothing we can do to help here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/seaglass/issues/detail?id=110) and also [this](https://code.google.com/p/seaglass/issues/detail?id=41) you will realize the cause.

Comment: Well, supposedly as of April 9th 2010 it is fixed.  But I've got to say, if the problem is with one LAF only, and it is a 3rd party LAF, I'm having trouble maintaining any interest...  If you want to persist using a LAF that claims a problem is fixed when it isn't, I guess that's your choice.